# llvm- Defining function in cpp and creating a call

Tags: llvm

In the llvm project tutorials, they usually have a Skeleton file in which an external function is called, while it's body is implemented in a c file whose .bc will be linked to have the resulting bitcode to find the external function. 
However, looking at the implemented LLVM projects in github, I do not see them using any c file and linking it to the resulting bitcode. 
My question is how I can define a function and create a call to the function. Is defining intrinsic functions the only way?

When defining a function in cpp, and having a createCall to the function, it does not find definition of the function defined in cpp when running the bitcode/or the binary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right, but will try to answer.

When you do `Function* myF = module->getOrInsertFunction("myF", ...);` you just create a **declaration** for it. Much like `void myF(...);` in C/C++ header file.

To turn `myF` into a **definition**, you create `BasicBlock`s, populate them with `Instruction`s and then insert these `BasicBlock`s into `myF`. This will make `myF` **defined** in your module and you won't see "definition not found" error anymore.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. To address the problem of getting "definition not found",  I had to implement the body of the function in a c file and link its generated bt. However, this is what I was looking for. However, my main concern is how easy/reasonable it is to implement a function LLVM instructions while the function itself seems very complicated when it is written in C--for example, it uses pointer casting, struct, reinterpretation, etc.